# Why does this python code when run cause slowdowns and why does it not return anything?

Tags: python

I wrote this code:

```
List = [1,2,3,5,8]
for i in List:
    if i != 100:
        List.append(int(List[-1])+int(List[-2]))
print(List)
```

Why doesn't it return anything, and why does it cause slowdown when run?

Comment: Because you're mutating `List` inside a loop. What do you expect to happen with `for i in List:` if you keep appending on literally every iteration?

Comment: That's an infinite loop. You're iterating through your list and adding more stuff to it as you go.

Comment: @khelwood Infinite until it raises `MemoryError` ;-)

Comment: @alaniwi Just like every infinite loop is only infinite until you kill the program, or your computer goes off, or the heat death of the universe. Whichever is soonest.

Comment: @khelwood “[Linux] does endless loops in six seconds.” - https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code slows because the list grows infinitely large as you append while looking at the last two elements.

Code should return *something*, most notably an Out of Memory Error

Answer (score 1):

Use `<=` instead of `!=`

```
List = [1,2,3,5,8]
for i in List:
    if i <= 100:
        List.append(int(List[-1])+int(List[-2]))
print(List)
```

If you just use `!=`, you will keep adding items forever and never stop - since 100 will never appear in this list.

Also, try to think how you can implement this **without** modifying the list **while you're iterating it.** It's really confusing to read loops that modify the list they're iterating over, and considered bad practice.